# declaring css properties in a css file for jquery .animate()

Tags: jquery

While implementing jquery `.animate()`, I've to write like

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    width: '200px',
    height: '500px'
  })
})
```

Isn't there some way to write the css properties in a css file and just do the 'animate' by including the css property??

Something like

```
.move{
    width: '200px',
    height: '500px'
}
```

Then

```
$('#book').animate({
    // include the .move css class somehow 
})
```

I tried using `$( "#effect" ).addClass( "newClass", 1000 );` but there is no animation, the properties just seem to be assigned after the duration declared!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery UI project extends the `addClass` method to allow exactly what you're looking for.

[jQuery UI - `addClass`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/).

Comment: I tried that but I see not eased animation. The properties just seem to be assigned after the duration I declared.

Comment: @ptamzz: This requires you to include the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library **in addition** to jQuery.

Comment: It's already there. If it should be animated by using `addClass()`, then something's wrong in my codes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you can switch a complete stylesheet, but you can switch class with this plugin

http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/